# How to get selected item in JList into a string

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I'm having trouble actually retrieving items that I have stored in a `JList`. I am using Eclipse, which urges me to parametrize the `JList`, which I did (`String`), and I need a way to retrieve the values and store them in a `String` variable.

Initialization:

```
JList<String> songlist;

songlist = new JList<String>(list); //list is a DefaultListModel
```

User fills up JList with songs...

Then I try to retrieve selected song to display information about it:

```
String value = songlist.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

...and I get the error:

> The method getSelectedItem() is undefined for the type JList

Same happens when I try `getSelectedValue()` and `getElementAt()` (paired with `getSelectedIndex()`)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getSelectedIndex`() instead of `getSelectedItem`()

No such method exist in JList,for more detail refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Answer (score 1):

If your selection mode is SINGLE, use

- [`public E getSelectedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) - Returns the value for the smallest selected cell index; the selected value when only a single item is selected in the list. When multiple items are selected, it is simply the value for the smallest selected index. Returns null if there is no selection.

This is a convenience method that simply returns the model value for `getMinSelectionIndex`.

If your selection mode is MULTIPLE, use

- `public List<E> getSelectedValuesList()` - Returns a list of all the selected items, in increasing order based on their indices in the list.

---

See [**JList API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)